# Number of unordered pairs of linearly independent elements

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over $K$.

Let $K = \mathbb{Z}_p$, and dim $V = 3$.

We know that $V$ has $p^n$ elements.

I need to show that the number of unordered pairs of
linearly independent elements of $V$ is:

$$\frac12
(p^3 − 1)(p^3 − p).$$

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but you can find the number of $3\times 3$ invertible matrices over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$. There are $(p^3-1)(p^3-p)$ such matrices. In each matrix you have 3 vectors, so multiply by $3$ but unordered means that we have to divide by $3!=6$, Hence $\frac{1}{2}(p^3-1)(p^3-p)$

Answer (score 0):

Pick any nonzero vector. Then pick any vector not in the one dimensional space spanned by the first. Then ignore order.